# Fallout 4 Pip-Boy Android app stopped connecting to PC version running on Windows 10

Tags: fallout-4, networking, windows-10

After a recent beta update via Steam, the pip boy app (on Android) stopped working. It is able to detect my PC, and initially says 'success', then immediately says connection error. 
**It used to work before**, so this isn't a firewall issue.

**Edit** - Windows Firewall already has granted bi-directional full access on all ports and protocols to `fallout.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

For me this wasn't a networking issue.  It was the permanent modification I had made to my carry weight that the application didn't like.

You can check by starting a new game.  You have to run through until you exit Vault 111 and pick up the Pip Boy, but I wager the application will work for you for that game at that time.

Comment: Permanent modification? How?

Comment: Using the console, I entered "player.modav carryweight 9000".  But I think any modification to a game that's outside the boundaries of what Bethesda assumed can cause the same issue.

Comment: Hmm, I've been using the tgm cheat to carry more than the usual weight, maybe that's interfering with it?

Comment: Yea, try turning it off and seeing if you can connect, or like I said, start a new game and connect to it.  (At least the second option will prove that it's not a networking issue.)